# In R, how can I draw a negative (1:1 ratio) line in graph?

Tags: r, ggplot2

Here is a data

```
x<- c(10,25,35,45,55)
y<- c(30,50,25,17,17)
dataA<- data.frame (x,y)
    
ggplot(data=dataA, aes(x=x, y=y)) +
  geom_point (col="Black", size=4) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks= seq(0,70,10), limits = c(0,70)) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks= seq(0,70,10), limits = c(0,70)) +
  labs(x="x", y="y") +
  theme(axis.line = element_line(size = 0.5, colour = "black")) +
  windows(width=5.5, height=5)
```

[image]

I want to draw a 1:1 ratio line (not a regression). So if I add `geom_abline()`

```
ggplot(data=dataA, aes(x=x, y=y)) +
  geom_point (col="Black", size=4) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks= seq(0,70,10), limits = c(0,70)) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks= seq(0,70,10), limits = c(0,70)) +
  geom_abline (slope=-1, linetype = "dashed", color="Red") +
  labs(x="x", y="y") +
  theme(axis.line = element_line(size = 0.5, colour = "black")) +
  windows(width=5.5, height=5)
```

[image]

The line is not a full 1:1 ratio. If I add `geom_abline (slope=1, linetype = "dashed", color="Red")`,

it works well.

[image]

How do I draw a negative 1:1 ratio line?

Thanks,

Comment: Guessing you wanted something like `geom_abline (slope=-1, intercept = 70, linetype = "dashed", color="Red")` so that the line aligned with your plot corners?

Comment: Yes!! geom_abline(intercept= 70, slope= -1, linetype="dashed", color="Red") is perfectly working!!! Thank you so much!!!

Answer (score 0):

The -1 slope line you're drawing will intersect the origin [0,0]. I'm guessing you want to move the line so more of it shows. You can do `x = 'x' , y = 'y' + 70` in the plot coordinates. Replace 70 with `max(y)` for a dynamic plot?